# Regresar a MainActivity desde Actividad abierta con Intent

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación con tres actividades.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".OtherActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
    
    <activity
        android:name=".IntentActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Entonces espero el siguiente comportamiento

Al abrir la aplicación se abre MainActivity, luego con la aplicación aun abierta, desde Youtube comparto un link de un video, entonces se abre IntentActivity, hasta ahí todo perfecto.
Entonces ahora me encuentro en IntentActivity y **deseo regresar a MainActivity, como haría para lograr eso.**

Si hubiera abierto **IntentActivity desde MainActivity** seria tan facil como hacer `Finish()`, sin embargo este no es el caso, ya que IntentActivity fue abierto desde youtube a la hora de compartir el link.

También, ya que me encuentro en IntentActivity podría lanzar un **Intent que abra MainActivity**.

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Sin embargo esto no vuelve a la actividad ya creada, sino que crea otra instancia, eso es algo que no deseo.

Algo que resuelve el problema es agregar android:launchMode="singleTask" en el Manifiesto a MainActivity, ya que así al abrir MainActivity con Intent, se encontrará la instancia de MainActivity ya creada, y **me dirigirá hacia ella evitando crear otra instancia, eso es justo lo que quiero.** Sin embargo esto **genera un comportamiento que no deseo en mi aplicación.**

ESTE: Si abro OtherActivity desde MainActivity y paso la aplicación a segundo plano es decir salgo de ella sin cerrarla, y luego vuelvo a ingreso debería encontrarme con OtherActivity , esto pasa si no tengo `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, pero en este caso como lo agregue para soluciona el problema de anterior, cada vez que vuelvo a ingresar en lugar de encontrarme con  OtherActivity, MainActivity es la que aparece. Ya que "singleTask" hace que siempre aparezca en la parte superior de la pila.

Ejemplo con WhatsApp
Abro whatsApp me encuentro en su MainActivity, ahora voy a compartir un Imagen desde mi galería, se abre la actividad de Contactos a quien enviar el archivo, si selecciono un contacto abre una actividad para editar la Imagen. Si le doy a enviar, aparezco en la actividad de el contacto a quien se envió el archivo. Ahora desde esta ActividadContacto **puedo regresar a la actividad principal** presionando la tecla de atrás o la flecha de retroceder que se encuentra al costado de la foto del contacto.

```
 -> MainActivityAbierta

 -> Voy a mi galeria, comparto imagen
 -> Actividad contacto con quien compartir el archivo ---> **Actividad EditarImagen**, clic en enviar ---> Actividad Contacto, si presiono atrás o flecha de retroceder ---> **MainActivity**, en la que me encontraba **al abrir la aplicación no se instancio una nueva es la misma**.
```

**Que resalto aqui: el hecho de regresar a la actividad principal, desde una actividad que se abrió con un intent, incluso luego de haber navegado por mas actividades. Eso es lo que espero obtener.**

Y ademas como pude notar whatsApp no usa android:launchMode="singleTask", ya que si:
Abro whatsApp ingreso a ActivityAjustes, salgo de la aplicación sin cerrarla, ingreso y aparece la ActivityAjustes. En cambio si usara "singleTask" , volveria a MainActicity aun habiendo dejado la aplicación en ActividadAjustes o otra Actividad.

Como lo ve en el ejemplo con whatsApp es un comportamiento que se puede logra, sin embargo no he tenido mayor éxito, si tiene alguna duda de lo que deseo lograr hágamelo saber.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente pude encontrar una solución.
Si se encuentra en una actividad de su aplicación que no ha sido abierta por MainActivity, y quiere regresar a MainActivity sin que se recree, use.

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
intent.putExtra("name","redox")  //puede enviar lo que desee a MainActivity
PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).send()
finish()
```

El truco esta en usar

```
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
```

porque

> esto emula al usuario presionando la pestaña recientes y haciendo un
> cambio entre la pila. Esto es importante para mantener el estado de la
> actividad, es decir, sin lanzar una nueva instancia ni borrar nada
> sobre ella.

Según [esta publicación](https://medium.com/@veeresh.charantimath8/playing-with-android-task-affinity-and-launch-modes-5c36a0421e83) donde encontré la solución, **"solo use esta parte, el resto del tutorial trata acerca de otro comportamiento"**

Ademas cambiar

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Por

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).send()
```

Importante agregar

```
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

para poder recibir los valores enviados, atreves de  onNewIntent en su MainActivity, ya que como no se recrea no vuelve a llamar a onCreate entonces puede recuperar sus intents por medio de onNewIntent.

Puede usarlo en un botón o anular onBackPressed(), si desea.
**Con esto lograra regresar a su actividad principal desde otra actividad, que fue lanzada desde otra aplicación, sin que su actividad principal se recree.**